# Can I solve this hanging rope problem by using an uniformly accelerated motion formulas?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

> Question: A uniform rope of mass m
>   and length L hangs from a ceiling.
>   (a) Show the speed of a transverse wave on the rope on a function of y, the distance from the lower end. (b) Show the time a transverse wave takes to travel the length of the rope.

Hello, I came across this famous problem on Halliday Fundamentals of Physics.

The answer is (a)$\sqrt {gy}$ and (b)$2\frac{\sqrt L}{\sqrt g}$ . An ideal solution just includes the formula of the speed of the wave on strings and I easily solved this way as my first time solving this question.

What I want to ask is, Can I apply a formula for uniformly accelerated motion on this problem? My solution is under here:

> (b) $v^2=gy=2(\frac{g}{2})y=2as$,
>   $y=\frac {1} {2}(\frac{g}{2})t^2$,
>   so the time t is $2\frac{\sqrt L}{\sqrt g}$.

I also got the same answer on this solution, but I'm not sure if I can use this formula. Is it just a coincidence? Or why can I use this formula on this question?